# Limit construction process that avoids constructing a decimal like $x.99999999\ldots$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

> Each monotonically increasing sequence of real numbers that is bounded from above has a limit.

Below is a constructive proof of the statement above.

Let $(a_n)_{n≥1}$ be a monotonically increasing, bounded sequence where $a_n = A^{(n)}.\alpha_1^{(n)}\alpha_2^{(n)}\alpha_3^{(n)}\ldots$ with $A^{(n)} \in \mathbb N \cup \{0\}$ and $\alpha_j^{(n)} \in \{0, 1, 2, 3, \ldots, 9\}.$ By assumption, there's $T \ge 0$ s.t. $A^{(n)} < a_n \le T$ for all $n$. Now, $(A^{(n)})_{n\ge 1}$ is monotonically increasing, but it cannot fly off to infinity as it is bounded by $T$ so there must be some $n_0 \in \mathbb N$ s.t. $A^{(n)} = A$ for all $n \ge n_0.$ Similarly, there's some $n_1 \in \mathbb N$ s.t. $\alpha_1^{(n)} = \alpha_1$ for all $n \ge n_1$.

Using the algorithm above, we construct a number $a = A.\alpha_1\alpha_2\alpha_3\ldots$ The last step is to show $a = \lim_{n \to \infty}a_n$.

My question:

Consider $(\alpha_1^{(n)})$. One possible $(\alpha_1^{(n)})$ is $1, 1, 1, 1,\ldots, 1, 2, 3, 6, 8, 8, 8, \ldots, 9, \ldots$. Since $(\alpha_1^{(n)})$ is monotonically increasing, if/when it reaches, say, $8$, it never turns back and takes a value $< 8$, so it has to keep growing and eventually must reach $9$ and stay there.

So, how does this construction avoid the limit $A.999999\ldots?$

Comment: Does it help to answer your question that $A.999\ldots = A+1$?  (In standard analysis.)

Comment: A converging sequence needs not become "stationary". Consider for example $a_n=\frac{1}{n}$ which tends to $0$. In fact, becoming stationary is rather an exceptional phenomenon.

Comment: @Peter: true, but each decimal digit eventually reaches a stable state as long as we disallow such infinite sequences of $9$'s. Unfortunately we can't rule out the possibility of, say, $\alpha_n=0.999\ldots999$ (with $n$ $9$'s). This is the OP's problem, I think.

Comment: @TonyK Good point.

Comment: $(\alpha_1^{(n)})$ is not monotonically increasing. But it is monotonically increase for $n>n_0.$

Comment: It is not clear to me how you justify "Similarly, there's some $n_1\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\alpha^{(n)}_1=\alpha_1$ for all $n\geq n_1$". While true, this does not follow (at least in my mind) from the fact that the sequence is increasing and bounded and is instead a consequence of the sequence converging (which is what you are trying to prove in the first place). Is there a reason you don't wish to use the normal proof method by incorporating the supremum of the sequence?

Comment: @QC_QAOA For $n>n_0,$ $\alpha_1^{(n)}$ is monotonically increasing and restricted to a finite set of values, so yes, $\alpha_1^{(n)}=\alpha_1$ for $n\geq n_1,$ for some $n_1.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I'm sorry, but I'm still not understanding. Could you write out a full answer? I think that would suffice for OPs question and my own confusion

Comment: The real problem with this proof is that you are using decimals to represent real numbers, and the reason decimals represent real numbers is because of this theorem. So this proof is accidentally circular. Unless you have a separate proof that if $(\alpha_k)_{k=1}^{\infty}$ has $\alpha_k\in\{0,1,2,\dots,9\}$ then $$a_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n} \alpha_k 10^{-k}$$ converges.

Comment: Essentially, you have to prove a lot of intuition about decimal notation for reals for this proof to be “good.” It is a nice intuitive approach, but it assumes so much about one particular notation (decimal.) And, while we grow up, we think of real numbers in terms of their decimals, that is not actually axiomatically what real numbers are. Their representation, in *any* base, is just a way of representing them, and we have to prove this representation is “good.”

Comment: I agree with @ThomasAndrews that decimal representation is not a particularly good way to think about this problem.

Comment: A more direct approach is to use the completeness of the reals to show that any set bounded above has a supremum.  For a monotonically increasing sequence, this supremum is the limit.

Comment: @QC_QAOA, I skipped a lot of steps there to get to the point faster. See the following for a better exposition:  https://books.google.com/books?id=Bt47DQAAQBAJ&pg=PA97&lpg=PA97&dq=bounded+increasing+sequence+constructing+decimal&source=bl&ots=dNOhjg1X_K&sig=ACfU3U3XHD2K8Fx8PJI8ff9ukt19KMJmvA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiQ2q74qMH0AhVEmWoFHf3vBrAQ6AF6BAgfEAM#v=onepage&q=bounded%20increasing%20sequence%20constructing%20decimal&f=false

Comment: @BrianTung, then it sounds like the proof is saying every bounded (above), monotonically increasing subset of reals converges to $A + 1$, not just an arbitrary limit. But then the statement of the theorem says nothing about it. Does that sound correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Below is a constructive proof of the statement above.

Given that the statement above does not have a constructive proof, I highly doubt that.

For suppose that every monotonically increasing bounded sequence has a limit.

Given a Turing machine $M$ and an input $i$, define a sequence $\{a_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ by

$$a_n = \begin{cases}
  0 & \text{$M$ does not halt on $i$ in $n$ or fewer steps} \\
  1 & otherwise \end{cases}$$

Now $a$ is a monotonically increasing, bounded sequence. Take its limit $L$. Note that if $M$ halts on input $i$, then $L = 1$.

Take some $N$ such that $|a_n - L| < 1$.

If $a_n = 0$, then it cannot be the case that $L = 1$, since $|0 - 1| = 1$ is not less than $1$. Therefore, $L \neq 1$, and thus $M$ does not halt on input $i$.

If $a_n = 1$, then $M$ does halt on input $i$.

Therefore, $M$ either halts on input $i$ or it does not.

However, it is impossible to prove constructively that for all Turing machines $M$ and all inputs $i$, $M$ either halts on $i$ or does not halt (unless the constructive metatheory used is flat-out inconsistent). Therefore, it is impossible to constructively prove that all monotonically increasing bounded sequences have a limit. $\square$

The first way that your argument is nonconstructive is that there is no constructive proof that every real number has a decimal representation. The second, more serious way is in your argument that there must be some $n$ such that $A^{(n)} = A$, which is also nonconstructive.

However, classically, your proof is acceptable. Recall that it's perfectly legitimate for a decimal representation to contain an endless string of nines, and that $0.\bar{9} = 1$. The rational numbers with finite decimal representations also have an infinite one involving an endless string of nines.

A much, much easier approach is to simply use Dedekind completeness to take the supremum of the sequence.

Comment: Do I understand you correctly that the proof in the OP is just an elaborate construction of $A.99999\ldots \in \mathbb N \cup \{0\}$? My problem is that $A.99999\ldots$ is not an arbitrary number, but some kind of "per-arranged" integer?

Comment: @user999033 This has nothing to do with that. It is countering the idea that this is a constructive proof, by showing it cannot have a constructive proof.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, sorry for the confusion. By "in the OP", I meant "in my OP".  Anyway, seems like a weird thing to publish this non-proof (in my OP) in a textbook :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a good intuitive approach, but it requires you to prove a lot of intuition about decimal notation.

There is no reason to avoid $A.99999\cdots,$ because that is a real number, too. If you need to avoid that, you’d also need to avoid $A.399999\dots$ or any number that is “eventually” all $9$s.

The real problem is that this proof assumes so much.

In our youth, we are taught about real numbers in terms of their base $10$ notation, and we think of real numbers, intuitively, as base $10.$

But in real analysis, we have to prove things about base $10.$

So, for example, you assume that if $a_0.a_1a_2\cdots<b_0.b_1b_2\cdots$ then for some $k,$ $a_k<b_k$ and $a_i=b_i$ for all $i<k.$

That seems intuitive, but it requires proof. (And we know this doesn’t go the other way, because: $0.999\cdots=1.000\cdots.$)

Even the notion, used in your proof, that every real number can be written as a decimal number, requires proof.

You also use the notion that every decimal expansion converges. That is practically a circular argument, because the usual real analysis proof that decimals converge uses that bounded monotonic increasing sequences converge. You *might* be able to prove the special case that all decimal numbers converge without the general case, but that seems hard to me.

So, this is a nice intuitive approach to understanding the theorem in base $10,$ but as a real analysis proof, it has a *lot* of holes. It might be able to be filled in, by filling in all those intuitions about base $10$ representations of real numbers, but it takes some work to fill them in.

What you find, if you try this, is that these are very messy proofs. The real analysis proof, using the supremum of the sequence, is much simpler.

At heart, you should be learning in calculus/real analysis that all those intuitions about real numbers have proofs. Base $10,$ or any base, is just one way of thinking about real numbers. But the base $10$ representation is not the heart of what the real numbers are, despite what we learned in grade school and high school.

---

One particular way that you assume decimal numbers are real numbers is in the assumption that a real numbers can *constructively* be turned into a decimal representations. In fact, constructively, you can’t always tell if a real number $a$ even satisfies $a<1,$ or $a\geq 1.$

But even if you are given a sequence of real numbers in the form of decimal numbers, you can’t constructively determine $n_0,n_1,\dots,$ so you can’t construct your limit.

So this is not a “constructive proof.” As Mark Saving’s answer notes, there can’t be a constructive proof.